# Python web scrape data request error

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to retrieve the response json data by a web site that I call.

The site is this:

[WebSite DriveNow](https://it.drive-now.com/#!/carsharing/munich)

On this page are shown on map some data. With browser debugger I can see the end point

[end point](https://api2.drive-now.com/cities/4604?expand=full)

that sends response data json.

I have use this python to try scrape the json response data:

```
 import requests
 import json

 headers = {
'Host': 'api2.drive-now.com',
'X-Api-Key': 'adf51226795afbc4e7575ccc124face7'
 }
 r = requests.get('https://api2.drive-now.com/cities/42756?expand=full',    headers=headers)
 json_obj = json.loads(r.content)
```

but I get this error:

> hostname doesn't match either of 'activityharvester.com'

How I can retrieve this data?

Thanks

I have tried to call the endpoint that show json response using Postam, and passing into Header only Host and Api-Key. The result is the json that i want. But i i try the same call into python i recive the error hostname  doesn't match either of 'activityharvester.com'

Comment: Response shows "302 Found" page. You need to correct your script

Comment: I get a "bad request" with your new code, bit it works once again adding `'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'` in the headers. And your problem is not related to the API key, otherwise you would get `"code : 403," message ":" Permission denied. "`

Comment: I have set also verify=False and so works. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your script, nor your question. Why two requests and three headers ? Did you mean something like this ?

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
'X-Api-Key':'adf51226795afbc4e7575ccc124face7',
}

res = requests.get('https://api2.drive-now.com/cities/4604?expand=full', headers=headers, allow_redirects=False)

print(res.status_code, res.reason)

json_obj = json.loads(res.content)

print(json_obj)
```

Comment: Im curious, if you dont understand his question how can you post an answer?

Comment: @Craicerjack I don't undestand what "activityharvester.com" is and I'm not sure if the OP want to retrieve a single Json file or to find a method for scraping the entire website. In any case, this script will be useful to him.

Comment: Hi Ettore, sorry but i call 2 different end point for this reason. The response data that i would like use are show by a website that execute a internal get request. So if i call the second end point without the first the response is null. I have try your code but i have my same error:  hostname 'api2.drive-now.com' doesn't match either of 'activityharvester.com'

Comment: What is activityharvester.com ?

Comment: @ APPGIS I've re-tried changing the variable names and I  get once again "200 OK" and a Json. I try to understand why you get this response and me another one. I'm pretty sure that `requests` doesn't use any cache.

Comment: The script also works with `1293?expand=full` (the ID of Dusseldorf) and i've not visited this page.